# Azure DevOps Source Control Policies

Tags: azure-devops, version-control

Prior to using Azure DevOps as our source control we were using Visual Source Safe and had VSS server, etc.  Our current solution is hosted in an Azure DevOps Repo as shown below.

It seemed that in Visual Source Safe we could create policies that prevented users from editing a file that was "checked-out" by another user which prevented the need to merging code.  Basically you had to make sure that the the code was first checked in, do a get latest, and then check out the code in your workspace to edit it.  Is there a way to do this in Azure DevOps?  I've looked through all of the settings and policies and don't see anything on this at all.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC? Git works *very* differently from TFVC (or VSS, for that matter) and it's important that you read and understand how it's intended to be used instead of trying to replicate your old workflow in a tool that's not designed for that workflow. I cannot emphasize enough that Git is **fundamentally different** from VSS and if you try to use the same patterns you used before, you *will* be miserable.

Comment: @DanielMann, I'm using Azure DevOps as shown in the picture above.  I don't believe that I chose Git when creating the repo but I honestly don't remember.  Still, I'm trying to avoid merging issues.  We're a small team and I'm trying to avoid issues where two people are editing the same file at the same time.  I prefer then older check-in, check-out pattern.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use TFVC, which supports a more "classic" version control workflow.